# Adding a custom Android font in Eclipse Neo

Tags: android, eclipse

I am attempting to add a custom font to an older version of Eclipse (neon).  The font has been added to res/font but errors crop up when trying to set it in styles.xml.  Can a custom font be used without fontFamily?  Can fontStyle be used instead?

Comment: probably not related to your question, but why use eclipse ?

Comment: `but errors crop up when trying to set it in styles.xml.` please post these errors and show the code you're trying, it's too hard to guess what you're doing as your question stands at the moment

Comment: Using Eclipse as development environment for Android app has been abandoned long time ago. You should upgrade the project to AndroidStudio/gradle.

Comment: Due to a work constraint, I am being forced to use an old version of Eclipse with Java v8...  The Android build target is 4.4 (API 19) and I see most of fontFamily is 26+ unless the support library is used.  However, I wondered if a single font can be set as default without using it.